# Hibernate entity - join with condition

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have table/entity which has `varchar(255)` field that can store values of multiple data types and type field which indicates what kind of value type it is. I want to perform join only if data type is of certain value ie. document.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACT_HI_DETAIL")
public class TaskDetailsVariable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "TEXT_")
    private String value;

    @Column(name = "VAR_TYPE_")
    private String type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEXT_")
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "VAR_TYPE_ = 'document'") // this doesn't work
    private Document document; // this should be joined only if type is document

}
```

When I try the example above, I get the error because it tries to join all `LONG_` values. I have also tried `@JoinFormula` and `@Where`.

Comment: As it's a ManyToOne @Where must be used. Can you please post the stacktrace of the error message you get?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I get `Unable to find Document with id 0; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Document with id 0`

Comment: What's are the ID of TaskDetailsVariable and Document?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli like I said, it can contain various data types, and it tries to join ie. boolean type of value 0 to Document with same id, which does not exist. It ignores `@Where` annotation

Comment: No I mean TaskDetailsVariable is not an entity. It has no Entity and no Id annotation.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have editied question, TaskDetailsVariable is an entity and it has id...

Comment: Can you please also add the code of Document plus the whole stacktrace of the error?